# grep / awk - discard lines based on multiple columns

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I would like to discard lines based upon matches in multiple columns.  For all matching occurrences in column 1, check the corresponding column 2.  Only if all column 2 entries are identical, discard all lines.  If even one entry in column 2 is different, then keep all lines.

Example:

Discard the first 3 lines because every column 2 entry is identical for Bob. However, keep the remaining 4 lines because at least one entry in column 2 differs for Jan:

```
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Bob Blue
Jan Red
Jan Red
Jan Green
Jan Red
```

Comment: Is the file sorted on the first column?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: what if there is only one row for a particular column value.

Comment: @puresll - yes I can will be presorting by the first column

Comment: @ghoti - I have not tried anything. I did not know where to start :-(

Comment: @sarathi - the file will not have any single, unique lines. They are filtered out prior to processing.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt{,}
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    array[$0]++
    next
}

{
    counter = 0
    for (i in array) {
        split(i, holder, FS)
        if (holder[1] == $1) {
            counter++
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 2) {
        print
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Jan Red
Jan Red
Jan Green
Jan Red
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$0]++; next } { counter = 0; for (i in array) { split(i, holder, FS); if (holder[1] == $1) counter++ } if (counter >= 2) print } ' file.txt{,}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (although it is GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^\(\S*\s\).*\n\1/{s/\n/\x01/;ba};h;x;s/\n.*//;s/^/\x01/;/^\(\x01[^\x01]\+\)\(\1\)\+$/{x;D};s/.//;s/\x01/\n/gp;x;D' file
```

Explanation:

- `:a` loop marker
- `$!N` unless it is the last line, append a newline and the next line to the pattern space (PS)
- `/^\S*\s).*\n\1/{s/\n/\x01/;ba}` form all lines beginning with the same key into a single line, replacing newlines by the hexcode `01`
- `h` store the current PS in the hold space (HS)
- `x` switch the PS with the HS
- `s/\n.*//` delete the last line appended (this is not a match)
- `s/^/\x01/` prepend a hexcode `01` to the start of the HS (this is an imaginary newline for matching purposes.
- `/^\(\x01[^\x01]\+\)\(\1\)\+$/{x;D}` for those lines that are all the same i.e have no exceptions, switch the HS with the PS and delete those lines and begin next iteration.
- `s/.//;s/\x01/\n/gp;x;D'` those lines that do have exceptions, remove the added hexcode `01` added to the front, replace all other such codes with newlines and print the those lines. Then switch the HS with the PS and delete upto the the first newline and begin next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is in a text file named "test.txt" you can get it running:

```
cat test.txt | grep ^`cat test.txt | sort -u | awk 'BEGIN{split("", aux, "");ok="";} {if ($1 in aux){if (length(ok) > 0){ok=ok"\|"$1;}else{ok=$1;}}aux[$1]="";} END{print ok;}' -`
```

You can execute step by step to understand the commands, or you can ask me (the AWK part is a little bit complicated).

This way, the output is:

```
Jan Red
Jan Red
Jan Green
Jan Red
```

Edit: I forgot to add the backslash to the "|" grep's OR ;-)

Answer (score 0):

three simple steps:

```
sort -u temp | nawk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' > temp_file
nawk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if(($1 in a) && a[$1]>1)print $0}' temp_file your_file
rm -rf tempfile
```

You can incorporate these steps in  a shell script and then execute it

Answer (score -1):

```
KEY_STRINGS="`sort file | uniq | awk '{print$1}' | uniq -d`" 
awk -vkeys="$KEY_STRINGS" '{if(keys~/$1/)print$0}' file
```

I believe this script will be more easier to understand.