# Filter lines based on multiple columns

Tags: awk, terminal, compare, multiple-columns

I would like to filter lines based upon matches in multiple columns.
I have (various) 4 column tab-separated files. 
I need to check for all duplicate occurrences in Column 1, check to the corresponding column 4, if the values are different (even if only in one occurrence) print the entire line (of 4 columns).

Here is an example of the input:

```
function-n  such_as-handheld-n  6.4623  A
function-n  such_as-hash-n  6.5328  A
party-n such_as-head-n  2.5586  A
function-n  such_as-headphone-n 8.0794  B
function-n  such_as-health-n    3.1938  A
party-n such_as-heartbeat-n 6.5902  B
party-n such_as-heat-n  3.9708  B
zebra-n at-1-aquatic-n  10.0476 B
zebra-n become-pelican-n    12.4166 B
zebra-n behind-idea-of-concept-n    16.0319 B
zebra-n move-lion-n 12.2017 B
zebra-n such_as-1-pole-n    8.9519  B
zebra-n try-reasoning-n 12.9504 B
zooplankton-n   than-1-mangrove-n   12.0638 B
```

and the result would therefore be the following is the following:

```
function-n  such_as-handheld-n  6.4623  A
function-n  such_as-hash-n  6.5328  A
party-n such_as-head-n  2.5586  A
function-n  such_as-headphone-n 8.0794  B
function-n  such_as-health-n    3.1938  A
party-n such_as-heartbeat-n 6.5902  B
party-n such_as-heat-n  3.9708  B
```

as "function-n" and "party-n" are the only values in Column1 that have different values in Column 4.

I have seen this post on discarding lines based on multiple columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534402/grep-awk-discard-lines-based-on-multiple-columns) , using awk. 
The code (proposed by @Steve) is the following:

```
FNR==NR {
    array[$0]++
    next
}

{
    counter = 0
    for (i in array) {
        split(i, holder, FS)
        if (holder[1] == $1) {
            counter++
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 2) {
        print
    }
}



$ awk -f script.awk file.txt{,}
```

This code does exactly what I need, except for 2 column data.
I have tried to modify a part of the script to compare the 4th column as follows:

```
{
    counter = 0
    for (i in array) {
        split(i, holder, FS)
        if (holder[1] == $4) {
            counter++
        }
```

Yet, it does not work. Can anyone provide insight on how to modify this script so that I can achieve the desired result?

Or perhaps someone has a more efficient/optimised way to handle the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (using awk) is the following:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { if(A[$1]!=$NF && A[$1]){B[$1]++} A[$1]=$NF; next }\
  { if(B[$1]){ print } }' input input > output
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to work very hard with awk. You can't start printing until you've read every line, and the data structures I think you need are somewhat beyond what awk provides. You can use a higher-level language: Python, Perl, Ruby come to mind.

Here's ruby 1.9.3:

```
ruby -F"\t" -ane '
    BEGIN { 
        f4 = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new} 
        lines = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new} 
    }
    f4[$F[0]][$F[-1]] = 1
    lines[$F[0]] << [$., $_]
    END {
        output = []
        f4.each_pair do |key, subhash|
            if subhash.length > 1
                lines[key].each {|pair| output[pair[0]] = pair[1]}
            end
        end
        puts output
    }
'
```

Perl:

```
perl -F"\t" -ane '
    $f4{$F[0]}{$F[-1]} = 1;
    push @{$lines{$F[0]}}, [$., $_];
    END {
        @output=();
        while (($key, $subhash) = each %f4) {
            if (keys(%$subhash) > 1) {
                $output[$_->[0]] = $_->[1] for @{$lines{$key}};
            }
        }
        print @output;
    }
'
```

Comment: Thank you: I have tried your code but it gives me the following error: ruby:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
ruby -F"\t" -ane '
        ^
ruby:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '('

Comment: what version of ruby do you have? `ruby --version`

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.8.6

Comment: I tested this with 1.9.3.  Would a translation to Perl be helpful?

Comment: Yes, it would be great to have comparisons in different methods to solve the problem.